# Regarding google ad personalization

Tags: personalization, google-ads-script

To increase programmatic revenue, we would like to have a new key-value entered into the source code on Desktop, XS .
This key value will differentiate users who have disabled personalized ads vs users who have no restrictions which will allow us to increase programmatic CPM’s by serving more open auction banners to users with no restrictions.

Key-value has been created within GAM

Personalized_Ads=ENABLED OR DISABLED

Can we sense the google ads personalizations setting in user were turned on or off?